# Concurrently enumerating an array using blocks in a thread-safe way

Tags: array, objective-c, thread-safety, file-system, concurrency

I have an array that I want to enumerate using blocks concurrently.  However, I'm having trouble making this thread safe. I am new to using blocks and locks, so I am hoping someone may be able to push me in the right direction for preventing this from crashing.

The point of this function is to loop over a number of files and folders.

- if folder, create a new dictionary item
- if file, add as child to folder key
- if folder, then recursively move into the folder to iterate over all files and folders and add to dictionary

This builds a dictionary structure of the file system.  However, it is slow and I would like to do this concurrently.

My main function looks like this:

```
- (void)createDirectoryStructure:(NSString *)LR withArray:(NSMutableArray *)myArray {

    __block NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    __block BOOL isDir=NO;
    __block NSString *local;
    __block NSString *myKey;

    [myArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        NSString *url=obj;
        if ([LR isEqualToString:@"L"]) {
            myKey = [url stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
            local = [self.rootdirL.path stringByAppendingString:url];
            [fm fileExistsAtPath:local isDirectory:&isDir];
            if (!isDir)
                [self updateStructureWithKey:myKey andURL:url isDir:isDir forLR:LR];
        }
    }];
}
```

This function calls `updateStructureWithKey` that looks like this:

```
-(void) updateStructureWithKey:(NSString*)myKey andURL:(NSString*)url isDir:(BOOL)isDir forLR:(NSString*)LR
{
    NSArray *components=[myKey pathComponents];
    NSString *addPath=@"";
    NSUInteger counter=0;

    for (NSString *component in components){

        NSString *createDir=[addPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:component];
        addPath=createDir;

        counter+=1;
        if ((unsigned long)counter<(unsigned long)components.count){
            NSString *addchild = [createDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[components objectAtIndex:(unsigned long)counter]];

            [self addDictionaryItem:createDir withURL:addchild withLR:LR isDir:TRUE];
        }
    }

    [self addDictionaryItem:myKey withURL:url withLR:LR isDir:isDir];

}
```

Which again calls `addDictionaryItem`:

```
-(void) addDictionaryItem:(NSString *) mykey withURL:(NSString *)myurl withLR:(NSString *)LR isDir:(BOOL) myIsDir
{
    if ([self.dict objectForKey:mykey]) {
        NSMutableArray *myarray = [[self.dict objectForKey:mykey] objectForKey:@"myarray"];
        NSMutableArray *myarrayLR = [[self.dict objectForKey:mykey] objectForKey:@"LR"];
        NSMutableArray *myarrayIsDir = [[self.dict objectForKey:mykey] objectForKey:@"isdir"];

        NSMutableDictionary *attrDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myarrayLR, @"LR",
                                                                                      myarray, @"myarray", myarrayIsDir, @"isdir",
                                                                                      nil];

        if (![myarray containsObject:myurl]){
            [myarray addObject:myurl];
            [myarrayLR addObject:LR];
            [myarrayIsDir addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:myIsDir]];

            if ([theLock tryLock]) {
                [self.dict setObject:attrDict forKey:mykey];
                [theLock unlock];
            }       
        }
        else {
            NSMutableArray *arrayOfFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [arrayOfFiles addObject:myurl];

            NSMutableArray *arrayOfLR = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [arrayOfLR addObject:LR];

            NSMutableArray *arrayIsDir = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [arrayIsDir addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:myIsDir]];

            NSMutableDictionary *attrDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:arrayOfLR, @"LR",
                                                                                      arrayOfFiles, @"myarray", arrayIsDir, @"isdir",
                                                                                      nil];
            if ([theLock tryLock]) {
                [self.dict setObject:attrDict forKey:mykey];
                [theLock unlock];
            }
         }
     }
}
```

In the final function, I use an `NSLock` that is initialized as a property earlier. I thought that since the functions `updateStructureWithKey` and `addDictionaryItem` are defined inline of the block, I would not have to define their variables as `__block`, but since I am changing a property, I would have to use NSLock to make sure the change is thread safe.

Still, when I run this code, it crashes with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)", but the position where it crashes varies.

A simplified test version of this problem is available as a Xcode project on [GitHub](https://github.com/trondkr/testFiletree).

I appreciate suggestions and hints from anyone who can help me understand blocks and thread safety.

Comment: Use Xcode Menu Product > Profile then Instruments with "Time Profiler" to see where most time is spent. And @synchronized is the easiest way to protect access to mutable objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The bottleneck of your code might not be where you think it is. I recommend reading the [Performance Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001410-CH202-SW1) of Apple as well as the specific [File-System Performance Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/FileSystem/FileSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000161i).
2. Typically the bottleneck is at accessing the drive. So in making your build-up of Dictionaries concurrent, you will not gain anything as there is only one drive. You are checking with NSFileManager on each item with `fileExistsAtPath` which might be the bottleneck. Try getting this information initially when building `myArray`. You're probably doing this also with Directory  Enumerator. There are options to get specific metadata directly for an URL (like if it's a directory or folder) and this then will be cached in the `NSURL` (instead of working with path strings).
3. Did you try to set some Breakpoints to find more details about `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`? Is it because of objects that were released too early? Or is it because of mutated while enumerating? Set a breakpoint on "All Exceptions" in Xcode and run the code with debugger. You will then be able to find more details on the crash.
4. To isolate the crash, try to make the code in your block smaller. Remove all the code not really needed like this whole `LR` thing.

I've analyzed the provided code which is not recursive. See [my GitHub for the edits](https://github.com/mahal/testFiletree). Here are my findings (for a test directory with 27’861 nested items):

- Most time was spent in the enumeration getting Filesystem metadata:

  > ```
  >   Time     Self    Symbol Name
  > 3568.0ms  53.6%   -[SDAppDelegate createDirectoryStructure]
  > 2680.0ms  40.2%   -[NSURLDirectoryEnumerator nextObject]
  > ```

  The new code only fetches as much metadata as needed and reuses it by using NSURL.
- The code for filling the array also did lots of duplicate checks:

  > ```
  >   Time      Self    Symbol Name
  > 2997.0ms   45.0%    -[SDAppDelegate createArraysForLocalDirectories]
  > 2109.0ms   31.6%    -[SDAppDelegate addDictionaryItem:withURL:isDir:]
  > 1121.0ms   16.8%    -[NSArray containsObject:]
  > ```

  The new code does it a bit simpler.  It could be even simpler, see comment in code.
- Another thing was Memory management.  I removed the nested `autoreleasepool`, it's not really needed.  See "[Use Local Autorelease Pool Blocks to Reduce Peak Memory Footprint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-SW2)"
- As for concurrency, you were checking the mutable `self.dict` always if some key exists. If you want to write to this dict, you have to synchronize the access to it with a lock. The simplest one is [@synchronized()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW3).
- The improved code runs on the very same directory structure with the following times:

  > ```
  >   Time     Self    Symbol Name
  > 735.0ms    6.6%    -[SDAppDelegate createDirectoryStructure]
  > 268.0ms    2.4%    -[SDAppDelegate createArraysForLocalDirectories]
  > ```
- You could make a recursive code by using making a method that uses `NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsSubdirectoryDescendants` and then call this method inside it again for directories. But that probably doesn't really speed it up.

Comment: Thanks for your very useful comments and suggestions. I created a simplified version of my problem available on github. If you would take a look that would be greatly appreciated (https://github.com/trondkr/testFiletree). I have continued to work on this problem with no further success and could need some help. Thanks. T.